# Toggle a Google font effect with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-font-api

I am trying to create a small hidden button for a webpage that will toggle a [Google font effect](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started#Effects) on all of the `h1` elementss on the page but I'm not entirely sure how to go about it or if it's even doable. Here is the code I have so far, any guidance here would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(".flameOn").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find("h1").toggleClass("font-effect-fire");
});
```

The `.flameOn` class is attached to the button being hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely here:

```
$this.find("h1").toggleClass("font-effect-fire");
```

What you are, in effect, doing is trying to find h1 elements within the clicked flameOn class element, which of course makes no sense.  You probably just need your click handler to look like this:

```
$(".flameOn").click(function(){
    $("h1").toggleClass("font-effect-fire");
});
```

Comment: ::face-palm:: thanks, quite a simple concept, wasn't seeing it before for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having has to do with the fact that you are using `this` to search for `h1` tags. The jQuery click handler sets the function context (i.e. `this`) to the clicked element. When you call the `find` method on a jQuery object, it will attempt to find all of the *child* nodes that meet your search criteria.

```
$('.flameOn').click(function(){
  var $this = $(this);  // In this context 'this' is the '.flameOn' button.
                        // You should also note that 'this', by default is 
                        // already jQuery object, there is no need to wrap 
                        // it in the $() again.

  $this.find('h1')  // This will almost certainly return an empty nodeList rather
                    // than all of the h1s on your page. At best it will return
                    // any h1s contained within the button.flameOn tag
});
```

In essence, what you are trying to do with the above code is find all of the `h1`s inside of your `.flameOn` class, which doesn't make much sense given that it's a button.

What you really want is to simply use the vanilla `$` selector to find all `h1`s and toggle the class you want:

```
$('.flameOn').click(function(){
  $('h1').toggleClass('font-effect-fire');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Didact+Gothic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script language="javascript">
function Style(enable) {
  if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return;
  links=document.getElementsByTagName("link");
  links[0].disabled=!enable;
}
Style(true);
// disables font
Style(false);
// enables font
</script>
```